# counting words with or Whitespace with collections.counters

Tags: python

I'm doing a word count of a source code, and for example, I want to know how many `for` there are in a txt, for now it does well, but in some cases programmers write this way: `for(` or `for (`. In my case my code only counts the `for (` with the space but not without the space, how could I solve this?. Also in some cases, programmers put for example, `for(xxx` or `for (xxx` or `for ( xxx`, how could I make only for ?

```
from collections import Counter

words_to_keep = {"for", "setup()", "loop()"}

def word_count(filename):
    with open('hello.txt', 'r') as f: # use `filename`
        return Counter(w for w in f.read().split() if w in words_to_keep)

counter = word_count('hola.txt')

for i in counter:
    print (i, ":", counter [i])
```

Comment: you could use `.replace(' (', '(')` before doing the split...

Comment: @Thruston  I guess you meant the other way around...

Comment: `with open('hello.txt', 'r')` replace `hello.txt` by filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you observed, the problem with `split` is that you need your words to be surrounded with spaces but that not always true with code. Probably regex is your best option to handle the more general case of string matching.

This first [compiles](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) a pattern by OR-ing your accepted words (after [escaping](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) them), [finds all matches](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.findall) of the pattern, then counts the matches of the regex on the file:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

words_to_keep = {"for", "setup()", "loop()"}

pattern = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(word) for word in words_to_keep))
# in this case, pattern = "for|setup\(\)|loop\(\)"

def word_count(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        words_found = pattern.findall(f.read())
        return Counter(words_found)

for word, count in word_count('test.txt').items():
    print (word, ":", count)
```

If the file is big and you don't want to read it all at once, you can use the benefits of adding [`Counter`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```py
def word_count(filename):
    counter = Counter()
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            counter += Counter(pattern.findall(line))
        return counter
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it worked perfectly. I hope I'm not being rude, could you explain a little more about the pattern?

Comment: Sure. First of all you can use https://regex101.com/ to play around with patterns and even get explanations. The pattern is pretty basic: Simply joins your words with a `|`. This is the OR operator, which means `for|setup` will match either `for` ***OR*** `setup` whenever it encounters one

Comment: Now it is clearer. Thank you very much, I will continue to investigate

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the optional space(s) and the bracket using `re.sub`:

```
from collections import Counter
import re

words_to_keep = {"for", "setup()", "loop()"}

def word_count(filename):
    with open('hello.txt', 'r') as f: # use `filename`
        return Counter(w for w in re.sub(r'for(\s*\().*','',f.read()).split() if w in words_to_keep)

counter = word_count('hola.txt')

for i in counter:
    print (i, ":", counter [i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `Counter`:

```py
import re

def word_count(filename, words):
    res = {x: 0 for x in words}
    pattern = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(word) for word in words))
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for a in re.finditer(pattern, f.read()):
            res[a.group(0)] += 1 
    return res

words = ("for", "setup()", "loop()")
result = word_count('hola.txt', words)
print(result)
```